# How to get prefrences in XEP-0136: Message Archiving?

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, xmppframework

My Message Archiving is fine , message is saving in database easily but for some reason i want to fetch the preference set for xep-0136 .

As stated in [xep-0136](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0136.html) extension to get preference we need to send this IQ

```xml
<iq type="get" id="pref1">
    <pref xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive">
    </pref>
</iq>
```

But on sending this I am getting error in response that service is unavailable but i dont know how this can be possible ? because message archiving is working all fine. do i need to implement some other module.

**error iq**

```xml
<iq
    xmlns="jabber:client"
    from="ramu_gmail.com@##.##.##.##"
    to="ramu_gmail.com@##.##.##.##/42117879931439208568472324"
    type="error"
    id="pref1">
    <pref xmlns="urn:xmpp:archive"></pref>
    <error code="503" type="cancel">
        <service-unavailable xmlns="urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"></service-unavailable>
    </error>
</iq>
```

Guys please suggest.Thanks in advance.

Comment: ejabberd does not support xep-0136 officially. Where did you get that module? Are you really sure archive management is enabled?

Comment: please have a look at this link -- https://github.com/processone/ejabberd-contrib/tree/master/mod_archive i implemented from here